# Enable/disable hardware w/o Admin rights on Vista?

Tags: windows-vista, admin, device, access-control

I've been asked to provide a program/script/whatever that enables or disables the

- CD/DVD drive
- USB ports
- Floppy (!) drive

devices *without* requiring admin rights, that is, that can be run by a 'normal' user.

Ideally, something like a command line utility:
C:> foobar cdrom /disable

Any pointers, hints or clues gratefully accepted!

Thanks,

Rony

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a service that runs as a privileged account (e.g. Local System), and write a GUI front-end application which communicates with the server. The non-admin user can then run the front-end.

Answer (score 2):

Without finding a security hole in Vista, it just plain can't be done.  They require admin rights for a reason --- that's the type of things only admins should be doing.

There is a command-line utility (devcon.exe, available [here](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx/kb/311272)), which will enable/disable devices, but it's still going to require admin rights.  It's syntax is:

`DEVCON disable {device id}`   where {device id} is one of the "Hardware ids" listed under the "details" tab of the device's Device Manager property page.

Answer (score 1):

If you happen to be on a domain, I *think* you can disable all of that through a group policy.

Comment: Yes most likely the correct way of doing this is to set a policy in the domain. If not for disabling, so for allowing a normal user rights to do it. Check up on the Active Directory administrator instead ^^

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should check if user without admin rights can do it from windows ui, using Device Manager. And I really doubt it.